# Must declare the scalar variable "@User_Name"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, registration

Referring to my last question: "[The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137033/the-connection-was-not-closed-the-connections-current-state-is-open)". I am trying to do a registration form using vb.net with ASP.NET. After having solve an issue concerning 'close connection'. I am having problem to insert data to my database. When I try to validate the data it gives me an error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@User_Name"

Can someone help me to debug this? Thanks

```
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Partial Class Register2

Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

'declaring connection string and command
'here we are extracting connection string from web.config file
Private con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MauriAuctions").ToString())
Private cmd As New SqlCommand()

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Try
        cmd.Connection = con
        'assigning connection to command
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        'representing type of command
        'cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UserDetails (User_Name,Fname,Lname,Email,Password,Gender,Dob,Mobile,Address) values
        ' (@User_Name,@Fname,@Lname,@Email,@Password,@Gender,@Dob,@Mobile,@Address)";
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (User_Name, Fname, Lname, Email, Pwd, Street, Town, City, Tel) values(@User_Name,@Fname,@Lname,@Email,@Pwd,@Street,@Town,@City,@Tel)"

        'adding parameters with value

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Name", txtUser_Name.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", txtFirstName.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", txtLastName.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pwd", txtPassword.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", txtStreet.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Town", txtTown.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tel", txtTel.Text.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        con.Open()
        'opening connection
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'executing query
        con.Close()
        'closing connection

        lblMsg.Text = "Registered Successfully.."

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message.ToString()

    Finally

        con.Close()
        'closing connection
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    'refreshing/reloading page to clear all the controls
    Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), True)
End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're clearing parameters after adding them. Try putting `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` before first `.AddWithValue`, *not* after the last one.

Comment: Unrelated, but the `TextBox.Text` and `Exception.Message` properties are already `string`s. You don't *need* to call `ToString` on them, though it's not harmful to do so.

Comment: @pmcoltrane - And that goes for the Text propery of all of the textboxes too!